# Correctly upload an image to database. Laravel vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to upload an image to the database but no matter what I try I either get this error

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

or it says it saved correctly but it doesn't save anything

The following code is in the vue.js file in the submit function for the form where this the image is being uploaded. This is what I've tried to send the file to the controller

This gives me the error above

```
if (this.form.file && this.form.imageUrl) {
    this.form.file = this.form.imageUrl;
} else {
}

var data = Converter.objectToFormData(this.form);

this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
    if (valid) {
        this.loading = true;
        if (!this.form.id) {
            //send code
        } else {
            //send updated
        }
    }
```

This also gives me the error above

```
let data = Object.assign({}, this.form);

this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
    if (valid) {
        this.loading = true;
        if (!this.form.id) {
            //send code
        } else {
            //send updated
        }
    }
```

This doesn't give me any errors, but nothing gets saved

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('question', this.form.question);
data.append('instruction', this.form.instruction);
data.append('survey_section_id', this.form.survey_section_id);
data.append('response_type_id', this.form.response_type_id);
data.append('questionOptions', this.form.questionOptions);
data.append('rank', this.form.rank);
data.append('num', this.form.num);
data.append('show_text', this.form.show_text);
data.append('file', this.form.file);

this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
    if (valid) {
        this.loading = true;
        if (!this.form.id) {
            //send code
        } else {
            //send updated
        }
    }
```

This is the code in the controller where the error gets triggered

```
$destino = 'img/questions';
$image = $request->has('file');
if ($image) {
    $imageFile = $request->file('file');
    $filename = Uuid::generate(4)->string . '.' . $imageFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $imageFile->move($destino, $filename);
    $preg->image = $destino . '/' . $filename;
}
```

if I `dd($imageFile)` it always returns null or false, my guess is that the file isn't being sent as a file but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or why this is happening, the `$image` returns true so it does go into that if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form, there was an error in a laravel 6  that forced me to do this before getting the image:

```
$destino = 'img/questions';
$image = $request->has('file');
if ($image) {
    $size = $request->file('file')->getSize();
    $imageFile = $request->file('file');
    $filename = Uuid::generate(4)->string . '.' . $imageFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $imageFile->move($destino, $filename);
    $preg->image = $destino . '/' . $filename;
}
```

I'm not sure if it gave me the same error, but the file was always null if you didn't get the size before,

Hope it helps!

Comment: I get a new error 
>Call to a member function getSize() on null

Comment: if you do a dd($request); at the begining of the function, what do you get?

Comment: It's quite large, but i'll add only the data 
#data: array:10 [▼
      "question" => "asdf"
      "survey_section_id" => "1"
      "response_type_id" => "1"
      "optional" => "false"
      "rank" => null
      "num" => null
      "file" => "blob:http://dev.unadeca.com/d0662bde-ddea-4e92-9dab-06e90ab62152"
      "imageUrl" => "blob:http://dev.unadeca.com/d0662bde-ddea-4e92-9dab-06e90ab62152"
      "show_text" => "false"
      "questionOptions" => array:2 [▶]
    ]

Comment: Ok, now change the $image value to this: $request->hasFile('file') and check if it pass the condition

Comment: I don't get an error, but in the database the image is set to null

Comment: I figured it out, I guess I wasn't supposed to set the file to the fileUrl in the submit function